Collision Monitor in Nav2 Not Working Properly: Polygons Not Displayed or Followed Correctly in RViz2
I am trying to reproduce this tutorial (binaries-source installation ubuntu 22.04):
demo-execution collision monitor nav121
I'm experiencing a strange issue with the collision_monitor node in the Navigation2 stack using ROS2 Iron. Here is a detailed description of the behavior:
Problem Description:
1- Activation and Deactivation Behavior:

The collision_monitor node only displays the polygons (/polygon_stop) in RViz2 when I manually deactivate and then activate the node on terminal (autostart not working).
When the node is initially active (with autostart=True in the launch file), the polygons do not appear in RViz2.

2-TF2 and Static Transforms:

There are recurring issues with TF2 transforms not being available, causing message filters to drop messages due to timestamp mismatches.

Adding static transforms as a workaround sometimes helps, but the polygons still do not function as expected.


Tf2 common errors after launch the collision estimator node:
[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1721250899.640392986] [amcl]: initialPoseReceived
[component_container_isolated-6] [WARN] [1721250899.640723455] [amcl]: Failed to transform initial pose in time (Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 12.345000 but the latest data is at time 12.337000, when looking up transform from frame [base_footprint] to frame [odom])

Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 139.369 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'

[rviz2-5] [INFO] [1721251055.414431037] [rviz]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_footprint' at time 21,807 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'

[component_container_isolated-6] [INFO] [1721251056.059229662] [global_costmap.global_costmap]: Message Filter dropping message: frame 'base_scan' at time 131.768 for reason 'the timestamp on the message is earlier than all the data in the transform cache'

3-Inconsistent Polygon Display:

Sometimes the /polygon_slowdown topic is not even published, and only the /polygon_stop appears in RViz2.
When the polygons do appear after manually deactivating and activating the node, they are frozen and do not follow the base_footprint frame as expected.


4- Behavior in Rviz2:

When the robot reaches the goal and stops, the polygon appears close
to the robot but remains static and does not follow the robot during
movement.

This behavior is inconsistent and makes the collision
monitor unreliable for use.


5- Reinstallation:

I have reinstalled navigation2, nav2_bringup, collision_monitor, and
other related packages from scratch using ROS2 Iron, but the issues
persist.

Launch File and Parameters:
Here is the launch file and parameters I am using:
collision_monitor_node_launch.py
collision_monitor_params.yaml
Video Evidence:
I will attach a video demonstrating the behavior described above:
Collision Monitor Polygon Visibility and Moving Issue
Similar Issues Reported

Collision Monitor polygons are frozen in place
Collision Monitor inn Nav2 not work

Additional Info here and better Video here: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/issues/4555
Is this tutorial not working for ROS2 Iron or am I missing important configuration steps needed, before trying this collision monitor demo? I have read the documentation and carefully watched Collision Monitor Tutorial Video,from  Alexey Merzlyakov, but found no way to fix this problematic polygons behavior (slowdown not appearing and stop not dynamic).

What troubleshooting steps have you taken? First question I've got is if you've echoed the topics to verify they're getting published, which would tell if it's a publication issue with your component or a visualization issue in rviz. Second question is if you're intending to use sim time and whether you've got it set in your publisher and in rviz (no parameter server in ROS2, it needs to be set on each node independently). Third question, if sim time parameters are all how you want them, is how time is getting set in your messages, because it looks like they aren't in sync with your tf output.

Hi @Chuck thanks for the attention.  I have echoed the /polygon_stop topic. Data appears just once immediately after launching the collision_monitor, but no data comes afterward, even if I check/uncheck the polygon_stop box in rviz2. Here is the command and output 'ros2 topic echo /polygon_stop' : https://pastebin.com/r9Bc1nPd

I had sim time issues previously but resolved them by reinstalling ros2 and navigation2 and setting the correct environment variables in my bash: export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=waffle
export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:/opt/ros/iron/share/turtlebot3_gazebo/models
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_cyclonedds_cpp After these changes, I am no longer facing sim time issues.

The collision_monitor node is active:
ros2 lifecycle get /collision_monitor
Output:
active [3]

@Chuck Composable Nodes vs. Traditional Launch:
One of my concerns is the difference between using composable nodes and the traditional launch method. In tutorial, the launch file keeps the terminal occupied until manually terminated with Ctrl+C. However, in my case, the terminal returns to the prompt immediately after launching the nodes, which seems to indicate the nodes are loaded into a container and the process finishes.
I suspect this difference might be affecting the continuous data publication, as the collision_monitor node might not be behaving as expected with composable nodes.

Finally I am just reproducing the official documentation turtlebot tutorial for iron distro, it should work...Could you make it work on your machine? https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/using_collision_monitor.html#demo-execution

Second Question: Both Launch files and its nodes are already set with sim_time:= True :  "tb3_simulation_launch.py" and "collision_monitor_node.launch.py".

I'm sorry, but I don't have the capacity to try to reproduce this. Digging in a bit more, though, why are you not getting any more messages? Rviz shouldn't be producing the messages, it should be consuming the messages. What do you see if you ros2 topic info your polygon stop message? What is producing it? What do you see if you ros2 node info that node? Does it start and die or does it stay running?

When I followed the link to the tutorial you were using, I saw this statement: Both polygon shapes in the tutorial were set statically. However, there is an ability to dynamically adjust them over time using topic messages containing vertices points for polygons or footprints. For more information, please refer to the configuration guide. which sounds to me like it exactly describes what you're seeing - you get a single static polygon that does not adjust over time. Have you tried testing with dynamic polygons?

Hi @Chuck the output is normal, the node is working, and topic "active" as you can check the output: https://pastebin.com/1j60Snj3 I will take a look in this description you said about static vs dynamic

I’m voting to close this question because it is a cross post with the issue tracker: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/issues/4555

@SteveMacenski it's not a cross-post to another StackExchange site, so I don't have an issue with leaving it open here.

I think that in general we should enforce the no cross posting without strong cross referencing, especially for places that have a high overlapping community as in this case. This ended up with two parallel conversations with different details. Future readers will be better served with one cohesive thread, and likely resolving it will be easier with everyone in the same page.  The main meta talks about it here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/is-cross-posting-wrong-to-an-external-site#141824

Hi Steve and Chuck helped me to understand this issue: https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/issues/4555
Just replying my own question too make life easier to other users:
1- To visualize both polygons on rviz2, is it needed to add the other polygons you wish (I was declaring just one inside the array) on collision_monitor_params.yaml
#polygons: ["PolygonStop"]
polygons: ["PolygonStop", "PolygonSlow", "PolygonLimit", "FootprintApproach"]

2- It is not needed to switch cmd_vel_nav to cmd_vel_raw in navigation.launch file.
3- It is also not needed to change Durability QoS to transient_local on rviz2, the system default (volatile) is the correct one
4- The polygons will just appear after the robot starts moving (since its functionality and visualization is dependent from cmd_vel output). Therefore when the robot is static initially, the polygon_stop or polygon_slowdown won't appear.
Result video: https://youtu.be/vnL7_CqBup8
